# Calculate exact count of distinct values for combination of 2 fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-aggregation, resthighlevelclient, elastic-rest-client

I have around 40 million records in my elasticsearch index. I want to calculate **count of distinct values for combination of 2 fields.**

Example for given set of documents:

```
[
 {
  "JobId" : 2,
  "DesigId" : 12
 },
 {
  "JobId" : 2,
  "DesigId" : 4
 },
 {
  "JobId" : 3,
  "DesigId" : 5
 },
 {
  "JobId" : 2,
  "DesigId" : 4
 },
 {
  "JobId" : 3,
  "DesigId" : 5
 }
]
```

For above example, I should get the **count = 3**  as only 3 distinct values exists :
[(2,12),(2,4),(3,5)]

I tried using [cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) aggregation for this but that provides an **approximate count**. I want to calculate the **exact count accurately.**

Below is the query which I used using cardinality aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
        "counts": {
            "cardinality": {
                "script": "doc['JobId'].value + ',' + doc['DesigId'].value",
                "precision_threshold": 40000
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried using **composite aggregation** on combination of 2 fields using **after key** and counting the overall size of buckets but that process is really time taking and my query is getting timed out.

**Is there any optimal way to achieve it?**

Comment: Please avoid using words like *crore* that are not globally understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting should be avoided as it affects performance. For your use case, there are 3 ways by which you can achieve your required results :

1. Using [Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) (which you have already tried)
2. Using [Multi terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html), but this is not  memory efficient solution

**Search Query :**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "jobId_and_DesigId": {
            "multi_terms": {
                "terms": [
                    {
                        "field": "JobId"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "DesigId"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
        "jobId_and_DesigId": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": [
                        2,
                        4
                    ],
                    "key_as_string": "2|4",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": [
                        3,
                        5
                    ],
                    "key_as_string": "3|5",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": [
                        2,
                        12
                    ],
                    "key_as_string": "2|12",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

3. The combined field value (i.e., the combination of "JobId" and "DesigId") should be stored at the index time itself as this is the best method. This is possible by using a [set processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-processor.html).

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/concat
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "combined_field",
        "value": "{{JobId}} {{DesigId}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index API**

When indexing the documents, you need to add `pipeline=concat` query param, each time you index the documents. Suppose a index API will look like :

```
POST _doc/1?pipeline=concat
{
    "JobId": 2,
    "DesigId": 12
    
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "jobId_and_DesigId": {
            "terms": {
                "field":"combined_field.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "aggregations": {
        "jobId_and_DesigId": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "2 4",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "3 5",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "2 12",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cardinality aggregation  only gives approximate count. Since there are more than 40K documents using precision threshold will also not work.

You can use [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). It will give accurate count but will considerably slower than cardinality aggregation.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Distinct_Count": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.list = []",
        "map_script": """
                            state.list.add(doc['JobId'].value+'-'+doc['DesigId'].value);
                      """,
        "combine_script": "return state.list;",
        "reduce_script":"""
                          Map uniqueValueMap = new HashMap(); 
                          int count = 0;
                          for(shardList in states) {
                            if(shardList != null) { 
                              for(key in shardList) {
                                if(!uniqueValueMap.containsKey(key)) {
                                  count +=1;
                                  uniqueValueMap.put(key, key);
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          } 
                          return count;
                        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```